# TTS in Colab using Vakyansh Model

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, text-to-speech

I am using Google Colab to run Vakyansh's TTS model for the desired input text. I have mounted the git cloned folder of Vakyansh on my drive and have entered the directory perfectly. However, the following piece of code, it gave me this error:

SystemExit: Error: /src/glow_tts directory does not exist

```
!git clone https://github.com/Open-Speech-EkStep/vakyansh-tts
!cd vakyansh-tts
!bash install.sh
!python setup.py bdist_wheel
!pip install -e .
!cd tts_infer
!wget https://storage.googleapis.com/vakyansh-open-models/translit_models.zip && unzip -q translit_models.zip

from tts_infer.tts import TextToMel, MelToWav
from tts_infer.transliterate import XlitEngine
from tts_infer.num_to_word_on_sent import normalize_nums

import re
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

text_to_mel = TextToMel(glow_model_dir='/src/glow_tts', device='cuda')
mel_to_wav = MelToWav(hifi_model_dir='/src/hifi_gan', device='cuda')

def translit(text, lang):
    reg = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]')
    engine = XlitEngine(lang)
    words = [engine.translit_word(word, topk=1)[lang][0] if reg.match(word) else word for word in text.split()]
    updated_sent = ' '.join(words)
    return updated_sent

def run_tts(text, lang):
    text = text.replace('।', '.') # only for hindi models
    text_num_to_word = normalize_nums(text, lang) # converting numbers to words in lang
    text_num_to_word_and_transliterated = translit(text_num_to_word, lang) # transliterating english words to lang

    mel = text_to_mel.generate_mel(text_num_to_word_and_transliterated)
    audio, sr = mel_to_wav.generate_wav(mel)
    write(filename='temp.wav', rate=sr, data=audio) # for saving wav file, if needed
    return (sr, audio)
```

I cannot crack how to get a .wav file as the output.

I used this as my reference:
[Vakyansh Model](https://open-speech-ekstep.github.io/tts_model_training/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to download 2 models from https://github.com/Open-Speech-EkStep/vakyansh-models#tts-models, then need to specify directories for both glow_model_dir and hifi_model_dir.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).